# SafeArea is being ignored in modal bottom sheet

Tags: flutter

Just noticed that the top SafeArea is being ignored when `showModalBottomSheet` is set to `isScrollControlled: true`.(I want my modal to fit the screen) Anyone found a way to fix it?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) => MyModal(),
)
```

My test modal

```
class MyModal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Modal'),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

I kinda temporary fixed it by setting height of modal content

```
SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 80,
        child: Column(
          children: ...
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: oh sorry my bad , not the height, but the margin , like so `margin: MediaQuery.of(context).padding`, i currently use this as i have a simliar use case like you

Comment: @AhmedKhattab I got it now.. Yes that would somehow fix it too. I was hoping to get the SafeArea working properly instead of do another workaround but yes it is another way of fixing it. Thanks

Comment: you can provide, the `top:false` to the `SafeArea` widget it should do what you need it to do, what about that ?

Comment: @AhmedKhattab. If you mean in SafeArea then it doesn't do anything

Comment: i just notice, why you have a nested safearea inside the root safeArea widget, why?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake.. I was only experimenting... I'll update that. That however doesn't make any difference

Comment: well, thats all that i can offer, sorry and hope you find the solution to this issue :)

Comment: There appears to be an [issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39205) about this

Answer (score -3):

If you're using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)
Try it

```
    final padding = MediaQuery.of(Get.context!).viewPadding;
```

Else you can pass parent context as param

```
    final padding = MediaQuery.of(parentContext).viewPadding;
```